# Get the coordinates of the corners of an image in python

Tags: python, coordinates, edge-detection

I have an image that has an object that looks like a shirt with transparent background.
I want to get the coordinates of the corners of this object in the image using python then get the x and y of the top-left most coordinate then get the width and height of the object.

So the end result should be:
{ x: number, y: number, width: number, height: number }

Thank you.

[image: trust me there is an image here]

Comment: Unless there is something else you haven't included, you should be looking at something like OpenCV and specifically a bounding box.

Comment: @hrokr can you teach me how

Comment: Post a smaller image.